# how to Specify which physical interface the VPN interface should use, Windows7

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, routing

I have two physical interfaces which both have internet connection different from each other, and I have VPN virtual interface. I want to specify for the vpn which physical interface it uses .. how is that possible in windows 7 ?

Comment: Even if you manage to do this, the VPN software may still force all data to go through the VPN - disallowing access to any local devices you're networked to.  This done to prevent you from slurping data off to unauthorized devices (NAS, printer, etc.) or sharing your VPN link with unauthorized devices.